# How common is it that the number of the shortest vectors in a lattice is exactly two?

Tags: lattices

The lattice $\Gamma$ in $\mathbf{R}^{m}$ with the lattice basis $\{ke_{k}\}_{k=1}^{m}$ has exactly two shortest vectors: $\pm e_{1}$.

My question is the following:
Among all the lattices with fixed determinant of the basis matrix, how common are the lattices that have exactly two shortest vectors?

("How common" should be rephrased mathematically, but I do not know how.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is not particularly well-defined currently. Any particular lattice $L$ defines a family of lattices $L_\gamma := \gamma \cdot L$ for $\gamma > 0$. One has that the shortest vector $\lambda_1(L_\gamma) = \gamma \lambda_1(L)$, e.g. one may always arbitrarily choose $\gamma$ such that $\gamma \lambda_1(L) = 2$ if one wants. Typically one must therefore normalize things somehow, for example choose $\gamma$ such that $L_\gamma$ has unit covolume (in other words, $\det L_\gamma = 1$). Are you assuming such a normalization?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I assume that determinant of the basis matrix is fixed. I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: One interpretation can be: what is the (topological) dimension $d_2(m)$ of the closed subset of lattices with two non-collinear shortest vectors? The dimension of the set of lattices being $m^2$. For the codimension $c_2(m)=m^2-d(m)$, normalization does not matter. It seems to me that $d_2(m)=2m-2$ for all $m\ge 2$, and thus $c_2(m)=m^2-2m+2$.

Comment: Where does the formula for $d_{2}$ come from? Besides, this is a small thing, but I believe your way to count the shortest vectors is different from mine.

Comment: @kazn My previous formula is actually false, I wasn't careful. Actually $d_2(m)=m^2-1$, i.e. $c_2(m)=1$, for all $m\ge 2$. Namely fixing a first shortest vector ($m$ dimensions of choices), the second one can be chosen within a subset of nonempty interior in the sphere ($m-1$ dimensions), and the $m-2$ others can be chosen freely at least in some open subset. I actually don't know what you mean by your "way to count" since you didn't define it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but hopefully useful anyway.

Any full answer needs to specify what "how common" means.
For example, one interpretation of this is

> How common among *mathematically well-studied lattices* is this property?

The answer here is likely "not very common". One way to rephrase your question is how common is it for a lattice to have kissing number 2 (or equivalently, to have $\lambda_1(L)\neq\lambda_2(L)$). Many common lattices encountered in math are root lattices, which are generated of vectors of (squared) norm 1 and 2. For example $\mathbb{Z}^n$, or $E_8$. Most (if not all) of these will not have your desired property. One can construct root lattices that have your property (let $L$ be generated by vectors of norm 2, and consider $\mathbb{Z}\oplus L$), but it will be somewhat rare in practice.

Another interpretation is

> How common among *random lattices* is this property?

Here, one can appeal to standard results on random lattices, e.g. the work of Rodgers.
For example

> Let $V\geq 0$ be fixed. Then as $n\to\infty$, the distribution of $\frac{1}{2}|(L\setminus\{0\})\cap B(V)|$, the number of nonzero vectors of $L$ up to sign that are contained in the open ball of volume $V$, converges weakly to the Poisson distribution of mean $V/2$.

Things to search are Rodgers integration formula or Siegal's integration formula.